# What does it mean $|A|<|B|$, when $A$ and $B$ are infinite sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

For infinite sets, $A$ and $B$, what does it mean to say $|A| < |B|$?   Does it mean that there is an injection $A \to B$?

Comment: And that there is no surjection $A\to B$.

Comment: It means there is an injective function $A \to B$ but no bijective function $A \to B$.

Comment: @egreg: This requires the axiom of choice. It is perfectly consistent that the axiom of choice fails and there are two set $A,B$ that there is an injection from $A$ into $B$, there is a surjection from $A$ onto $B$, but there is no bijection from $A$ onto $B$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I just mentioned the usual definition. I *always* assume choice. ;-)

Comment: @egreg: Did you choose this choice, to assume the axiom of choice? Or was it determined by some axiom... of determinacy? :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila While I believe that studying deeply the foundations of mathematics is worthwhile, doing the math I do without choice is nearly impossible: I need maximal left (or right) ideals in rings.

Comment: @egreg: Yes, I agree with that. The axiom of choice is quite essential for modern mathematics. Even me, who mostly tries to work out things without the axiom of choice, find it very difficult to work without it (e.g. in forcing one of the basic principles about forcing is equivalent to the axiom of choice). However the definitions of cardinals and their ordering does not require the axiom of choice, and it is pedagogically incorrect (in my opinion) to rely on it when giving them and having the first discussions about them.

Answer (score 3):

$|A|\le|B|$ means exactly that there is an injection $A\to B$. $|A|<|B|$ means that there is such an injection, but there is no bijection between $A$ and $B$. By the [Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Bernstein%E2%80%93Schroeder_theorem) this is equivalent to saying that there is an injection $A\to B$ but no injection $B\to A$.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of $|A|<|B|$ is this:

1. There exists an injection from $A$ into $B$.
2. There does not exist a bijection from $A$ onto $B$.

Equivalently, one can formulate it as:

- There is a subset $B'\subseteq B$ and a bijection from $A$ onto $B'$, but there is no bijection from $A$ onto $B$.

These definition, by the way, has nothing to do with infiniteness or finiteness. It works for sets in general.

For example, $|\Bbb N|<|\Bbb R|$. There exists an injection, $f(n)=n$, for example, but there does not exist a bijection as Cantor's diagonal argument tells us.

Answer (score 0):

In general (in a quasi-ordered set, say) $a<b$ means that $a\le b$ and $b\not\le a$. For cardinal numbers of sets, $|A|\le|B|$ means that there is an injection from $A$ to $B$. Thus, $|A|<|B|$ means that there is an injection from $A$ to $B$ but there is no injection from $B$ to $A$.

In view of the Cantor-Bernstein theorem, it follows that $|A|<|B|$ holds if and only if there is an injection from $A$ to $B$ but there is no bijection between $A$ and $B$. On the other hand, if we're dealing with order types of ordered sets, denoted by $tp(A)$, it would be wrong to think that 
$tp(A)<tp(B)$ means that $A$ is embeddable in $B$ but not isomorphic to $B$.